# Amazon Web Service monitoring

Tags: web-server, load-balancing, amazon-web-services, websphere, capacity-planning

I have deployed a web app on an AWS server. I have following questions:

**Monitoring**

- my websphere app server status capacity monitoring?
- uptime thru Amazon CloudWatch metrics?

**Load balancing**

- Autoscaling is for only AWS instances scaling and load balancing or it can handle the individual app server load balancing as well?
- Is app servers load balancing handled separately by us?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the Websphere portion for ya.

a.  Without other 3rd party tools (ITCAM, Wiley, etc... $$$$) The way to monitor WAS specific metrics, such as datasource usage is to view it using the Tivoli Performance viewer, available using the admin console..  On the file level, you can also turn on verbose GC on the app server level and monitor the heap usage of your Websphere java process.

b.  Load balancing on Websphere is usually handled by using the HTTP Plug-in, which can load balance requests to your applications across multiple app servers in your Websphere cluster/app server.  That is, of course, it assumes that you're using IHS (Apache with IBM branded on top of it).  What is the current setup of the web server layer?